# How do I generate SQL database script using C# or SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I generate SQL database script using C# code or SQL code?

[image]

We can use the `Generate Scripts` option from `ssms` but how do I generate SQL database script using code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use SQL Server SMO (Server Management Object) that includes exactly the features you're looking for. You can script single database, or specific objects. Actually, that's how SSMS does it.

Blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/generating-sql-backup-script-for-tables-amp-data-from-any-net-application-using-smo

MSDN sample for scripting database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205825.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx