# C# - Generate Database Backup Script In-Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In a C# application, I know using ADO.NET we can execute a backup command like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDb TO DISK='C:\\MyDb.bak'
```

and take a database backup and store it at some given location.

I want to take backup of database in-memory i.e. return the backup script content (schema and data) which I can later save as `.sql` file at some location.

Is this possible?

Comment: The `BACKUP DATABASE` command in T-SQL does **NOT** return a SQL-based "script file" or anything - it's a proprietary, **binary** format only.

Comment: Yes. That I know. Here what I mean is to return schema and data which we get when we generate script to new window

Comment: Well as I said - you cannot use `BACKUP DATABASE` for that. There are no options or switches to make this command return SQL scripts to create database objects and fill in the data....

Comment: My main issue is the user used for SQL do not have permission for running i.e. creating any physical file on disk. So I thought of getting the schema and data in-memory

Comment: To make backup of database the easiest way is to do a Deattach.  Then copy the MDF file in windows. Finally reattach the MDF file to the server.  Backups are only useful if you want to backup pieces of the database.  For large files I would recommend one of the SQL command line tools.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng But how can it do it from program and as I said user is restricted from any such IO related operations

Comment: Use Process class to call one of the command line utilities.  You could also create an executable that runs as admin to allow user to perform the operation.  Out SQL Server allows users to deattach and reattach the database without admin rights.

Comment: The application is hosted on shared server and does not have access to command utils like sqlcmd.exe

Comment: You can use SQL Management Objects to generate scripts, etc just like you would from SSMS (schema, data, both) . Perhaps take a look at that.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 If possible can you provide an example or some reference to it

Comment: You can achieve it using SMO, have a look at this thread here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978473/how-do-i-generate-sql-database-script-using-code-c-sharp-or-sql/36978564

Comment: Thanks to all for helping in comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved it using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO). Thanks to all the friends who helped in comments.

First, install `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` from nuget package manager.

The working code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

---

```
var script = new StringBuilder();

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(connectionString)));
Database database = server.Databases[databaseName];
ScriptingOptions options = new ScriptingOptions
{
    ScriptData = true,
    ScriptSchema = true,
    ScriptDrops = false,
    Indexes = true,
    IncludeHeaders = true
};

foreach (Table table in database.Tables)
{
    foreach (var statement in table.EnumScript(options))
    {
        script.Append(statement);
        script.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

File.WriteAllText(backupPath + databaseName + ".sql", script.ToString());
```